# Why Does Only One Page From My Wordpress Site Not Function With the Header?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, hyperlink, header

So, for the most part my website works perfectly fine, except for when you click under 'Services' (/what-we-do/property-acquisition/) and try to go into Contact (it tries to link to a what-we-do/property-acquisition/contact instead of just /contact/). Only that part specifically doesn't work for some reason? Thank you in advance to anyone that can solve this for me

https://staging.highmarkschools.com/what-we-do/property-acquisition/

I don't know why this is the only page that doesn't click into Contact, and that's the only part of the header that doesn't link?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to that page is just `href="contact"` which is a relative link. It doesn't break on only one page, it breaks on all pages that aren't direct children of home. It should be changed to `href="/contact/"`, where the leading forward slash makes the URL absolute.

Also, ideally you'd be building that menu using WordPress's menuing system which, unless you manually enter URLs, would take care of this for you.

Comment: This totally solved my problem, thanks so much! Next time I will focus on utilizing more WP functions like menus and such. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

it is because your button has been directed to the wrong link. You need to make sure the link in your button has the correct path.